# ReactJS with firebase.add undefined error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm studying ReactJS and Firebase. My code works fine but when I decided to add another field to my database using the form from my site it shows me an error that it's not defined. I tried to hard-code the values but `name_comment` doesn't change the values in my database at firebase. My code is shown below and the screenshot of the error.

My code:

```
const AddProfList = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [rating, setRating] = useState('')
    const [comment, setComment] = useState('')
    const classes = useStyles();

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setRating(event.target.value);
    };

    function onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        console.log()

        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('names')
            .add({
                name,
                name_comment: 'comment',
                name_rating: parseInt(rating),
            })
            .then(() => {
                setName('') 
                setRating('')
                setComment('')
            })
    }

    return(
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <form onSubmit = {onSubmit}>
                <h2>Add Professor Rating</h2>
                    <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                        <TextField 
                            id="outlined-basic" 
                            label="Prof's Name" 
                            variant="outlined" 
                            type="text" 
                            value={name} 
                            onChange={e => setName(e.currentTarget.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
                        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Rating</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                            id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                            value={rating}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            label="Rating"
                        >
                                <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={4}>4</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={5}>5</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={6}>6</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={7}>7</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={8}>8</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={9}>9</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={10}>10</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                <div className={classes.multilineSize}>
                    <TextField
                        id="outlined-multiline"
                        label="Comment"
                        multiline
                        rows={4}
                        variant="outlined"
                        type="text"
                        value={comment}
                        onChange={e => setComment(e.currentTarget.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="button-margin">
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                        Submit Rating
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

Screenshot of error message:

[image]

Comment: After you submit the form, the values that you try to send to API aren't have been set, so after the e.preventDefault() try to log them to see the values are set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue. I changed `const [comment, setComment] = useState('')` to `const [name_comment, setComment] = useState('')`

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving a name for `name` and `nameComment`, and it seems that `nameComment` is not defined.

One simple fix is to specify hard-coded values:

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('names')
    .add({
        name: 'value of name',
        name_comment: 'value of comment',
        name_rating: parseInt(rating),
    })
    .then(() => {
        setName('') 
        setRating('')
        setComment('')
    })
```

Comment: This is what i did before but when I do this and try to enter values in the form it doesn't change my hard-coded values. My hard-coded values are the ones that are sent to firebase and not the values from the form.  Also, "name" and "name_rating" works just fine. It's just the "name_comment" that says it's undefined.

Comment: As said: it seems that `nameComment` is not defined. We have no way to know why that is based on the code you shared. I recommend setting a breakpoint in `onSubmit` and checking the variables that you use in that code.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code and included more. I will try your suggestion and see if something works out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as in the Frank's answer name_comment is not defined it seems.

```
const [name_comment, setNameComment] = useState("")
.....
function onSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault()

firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('names')
    .add({
        name,
        name_comment,
        name_rating: parseInt(rating),
    })
    .then(() => {
        setName('') 
        setRating('')
        setComment('')
    })
```

}